# Is there a way to set the name of a Sytem.Threading.Task?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, task

A Thread object has a Name property but I cannot seem to locate the same for a Task.

Comment: What do you need the name for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the name in the threaded code, useful for debugging.  This worked:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Hello world";
            // Look in the Debug + Windows + Threads window now...
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Petar - it was my assumption that the only way such a request could make sense was to be able to in fact name the thread.  So you can easily find it the task back in the Threads window.

Comment: Excellent complete example.  Thank you very much.   I wish Microsoft had included it as a parameter of the task for scoping reasons but this will probably do.  I had to either add a break point on the readline statement or do break all to get the thread and task debugging windows to display anything.  I also changed it to use an infinite while rather than sleep so there was no rush to open windows.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't believe tasks have names. Each task has a unique [Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.id.aspx) which you can keep track of, but not a name.